# Client/Server with Java

Tags: java, tcp, server, client

So, I checked that like I'm flushing my PrintWriter(I set it to autoflush), the port the server is running on matches the port that the client is connecting to, the server was ran first, this is all running on localhost so no router/firewall problems but for some reason this isn't working.

```
public class Server {
public static ArrayList<String> Username = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<InetAddress> Address = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        for(;;) {
            Socket client = socket.accept();
            new Thread(new Runner(client)).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Runner implements Runnable {
private final Socket client;
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        String info = reader.readLine();
        System.out.print(info + "\n");
        InetAddress address = client.getInetAddress();
        System.out.print("Connected to: " + address + " & username is: " + info + "\n");
        Server.Username.add(info);
        Server.Address.add(address);
        int i = 0;
        for(String user : Server.Username) {
            i++;
            writer.write("[" + i + "] " + user);
            System.out.print("[" + i + "] " + user + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Runner(Socket clientSock) {
    client = clientSock;
}
```

}

```
public class Client {
private String host;
private int port;
private String user;

public Client(String hostname, String username, int portNum) {
    host = hostname;
    user = username;
    port = portNum;
}
public void connect() {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        writer.write(user + "\n");
        while(reader.readLine() != null) {
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", "hshsh", 33333);
    client.connect();
}
```

}

I tried running RawCap to moniter the traffic on localhost, but the output was abit too much for me.  I don't really understand TCP enuff to read that dump, and there seemed to be a lot of garbage in the output too.  The handshake looked to go ok, and I'm pretty sure the client and server connected.  I think my problem is with using PrintWriter and BufferedReader, and possibly how I close my resources.

After closing the server, I get this message from the client.

```
Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Client.connect(Client.java:23)
    at Client.main(Client.java:32)
```

I added a print statement, and the client connects fine.  Last note, I had an this error message in my last program, and it was a combination of my buffers not flushing and not closing resources.  This time, I have my PrintWriter set to autoflush, and I'm closing all my resources on the server side.  Do I also need to close them client side?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by isn't working?  Have you added any print statements for example or used a debugger to check variable values while running?  Do you get any output?

Comment: I have a few print statements within the Runner class, and I get no output.  The program just idles, I usually have to close it and I sometimes get an error message, sometimes don't.  All I could get outta the RawCap dump I read is that it seemed the server and client connect and the handshake looked to go well.

Comment: What error message do you get? This will help us a lot to debug. Can you try adding an output statement directly after the connect calls to see if it gets stuck there? Also please try stepping through the running code with a debugger, if you are using an IDE it will have one built in.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to use a debugger, definitely do need to get that down.

Comment: Now is a very good time to learn! It's not difficult, read the docs for your IDE if not sure.

Comment: please, add a title that helps to understand you question.

Comment: having abit of trouble really thinking of what to title this, mostly because I don't really understand the issue that well.... would "Networking trouble with Client/Server program in Java" be better or still too vague?